# Android: FragmentStatePageAdapter not updating ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I have android application.
Application minSDK:15

I have NavigationDrawer.
When click on first Navigation drawer menu item, my new fragment appears called MainFragment.
Everything is good, like in android tutorial.

Now in this fragment I need to implement simple ViewPager.
ViewPager will page Fragments.

Here is code:

```
public class MainFragent extends Fragment
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment_layout, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ArrayList<Books> books;
        BooksPageAdapter contentPageAdapter = new BooksPageAdapter(getFragmentManager(), books);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(contentPageAdapter);
    }

    private class BooksPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private ArrayList<Books> books;

        public BooksPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, private ArrayList<Books> books) {
            super(fm);

            this.books = books;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            return BooksFragment.newInstance(books);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }
    } }
```

And BooksFragment:

```
public class BooksFragment extends Fragment {
    private ArrayList<Books> books;

    static ContentFragment newInstance(final ArrayList<Books> books) {
        BooksFragment booksFragment = new BooksFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable("books", books);
        contentFragment.setArguments(args);
        return booksFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        books = (ArrayList<Books>) getArguments().getSerializable(“books”);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_books, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        updateUI(books);
    }

    public void updateUI(ArrayList<Books> books) {
        ListView listView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listView.setAdapter(new MyArrayAdapter(getActivity(), books));
    }

    private class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Books> {

        public MyArrayAdapter(final Context context, final List<Books> list) {
            super(context, R.layout.books_menu_item, R.id.title, list);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position,
                            final View convertView,
                            final ViewGroup parent) {
            final View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    Book book = getItem(position);
    textView.setText(book.getTitle());
            return row;
        }
    }
}
```

The FirstPage looks awesome, like it should. I see list of books titles.
But on the second page, list view is empty. All other views on second page (like TextView..) are fine except ListView.
What I do wrong ?

P.S FragmentStatePageAdapter is from support13. Fragments are from android package, not from support4

Comment: add this `listView.invalidate();` at the end of `updateUI`. and tell me the result.

Comment: the same behavior. ListView is empty, not drawn at all

Comment: And what does it do if you make a listView.getAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged () at the end of the updateUI